# Typescript Objects

Tags: typescript, object, javascript-objects

Please assist, am trying to transform an object to an instance of something.
I have the following data as object from an API:

```
{
"0": {
    "0": {
        "1": 2
    },
    "1": {
        "1": 5
    },
    "2": {
        "1": 9
    },
    "3": {
        "1": 3
    },
    "4": {
        "1": 1
    }
},
"1": {
    "0": {
        "1": 7
    },
    "1": {
        "1": 6
    },
    "2": {
        "1": 10
    },
    "3": {
        "1": 8
    },
    "4": {
        "1": 4
    }
  }
}
```

my enums are as follows :

```
  export enum Enum3 {
    week1 = 0,
    ....
    week4
  }


   export enum Enum2 {
        day1 = 0,
        .....
        day10
   }

   export enum Enum1 {
        monday = 0,
        .....
        friday
   }
```

tried the following to declare but didn't work:

```
         // number is the number of racers entering the race
        let RaceDay: {[key: Enum1 ]: number };
        let Days: {[key: Enum2 ]: RaceDay[Key] };
        let Weeks: {[key: Enum3 ]:  Days[Key] };

        Weeks = ApiData; // data above.
```

How do i declare or instantiate such an object ? 
thank you.

Comment: A bit more code would be helpful. For example the Enum declaration

Comment: What is the code that gets the JSON from the API? You are probably not deserializing your JSON. Probably there is missing a call to `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: hi, i've edited the question see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 3 times nested object structure:

```js
interface RaceDay {
  [key: string]: number
}
interface Days {
  [key: string]: RaceDay
}
interface Weeeks {
  [key: string]: Days
}

const data: Weeks = { } as Weeks; // your object with type of 'Object' as above
```

assigning your object works for me. Hope that's helping.

Comment: i am getting the following error  `Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Weeks'. The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?`

Comment: Are you using angular httpclient or similar? Maybe try `const data: Weeks = {} as Weeks`. If you use something like httpClient from angular you can do `this.http.get<Weeks>(url);`.

Comment: if your data is type 'Object' the `as Weeks` at the end should work. Tested it.